# Coordinates are missing when sentinel 2 (.jp2) all bands are stacked and converted to tiff with python

Tags: python, geospatial, coordinate-systems, satellite-image, sentinel2

I downloaded zip file from data.copernicus.eu, then ran the following code. I can see coordinates in jp2 but not in tiff. I need to see lat/lan coordinates in tiff.

```
s2_sentinel_bands.sort()
s2_sentinel_bands

stacked_s2_sentinel = []
for img in s2_sentinel_bands:
    with rio.open(img, 'r') as f:
        stacked_s2_sentinel.append(f.read(1))
```